# Generalize Method to 'Get' Any Object Property

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, properties

Say I have a Dictionary object which contains many instances of an object called SomeObject and each SomeObject has properties named Property1 and Property2. Now say I have a method which can return a new Dictionary sorted by Property1.  However, I'd like to generalize that method such that I can tell it *which* property to sort by.

For example, to do this, I know I could easily have two separate methods such as:

```
public Dictionary<string, SomeObject> SortByProp1(Dictionary<string, SomeObject> dict) { ... }
public Dictionary<string, SomeObject> SortByProp2(Dictionary<string, SomeObject> dict) { ... }
```

But, I'm wondering if it's possible to combine these into one method in which I can give a parameter to identify which method to return?  I don't know of a way to generalize a property like that...

Note: I **do** realize I could always use something like an if-statement which could be based on a string of the property name, but that doesn't seem like a very elegant, acceptable answer much better than just having two separate methods to begin with.

Comment: A `Dictionary` cannot be sorted. You need a `SortedDictionary` in the return value.

Comment: A SortedDictionary is sorted on the Key, I need to sort based on one of the properties of the Values. I already have the method implemented, but only with a given property (meaning I need multiple methods to sort on different properties of the Values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you seek is built into the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, and is `OrderBy`, though it might not work out as smothly for a Dictionary as you might like.

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so its OrderBy method takes a lambda expression which itself takes a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, and returns a selector method that describes what you're sorting by.

For example, if you have `Dictionary<int, Customer>`, this will return to you an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Customer>>` sorted by customer name:

```
myDict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Name);
```

Then to get just the customers themselves in this sorted order, you'd say:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> orderedByName = myDict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value.Name).Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Indeed passing a lambda expression or any other delegate is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try adding a **generic type parameter**, for the ordering key - and accept a predicate for the ordering?

Such as:

```
public Dictionary<string, SomeObject> SortByProp<TProp>(Dictionary<string, SomeObject> dict, Expression<SomeObject,TProp> orderPredicate) 
{
   return dict.OrderBy(orderPredicate);
}

// Usage: 
SortByProp(apples, x => x.AppleColor);
SortByProp(oranges, x => x.OrangeType);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accept a delegate to select the property:

```
public Dictionary<string, SomeObject> Sort<TProperty>(Dictionary<string, SomeObject> dict, Func<SomeObject, TProperty> selector) { ... }
```

You can call it like this:

```
var sortedDict = Sort(dict, o => o.Property1);
```